# css resize / jquery resizable with $modal angular

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, resizable

I'm hoping somebody can shed light on what the delio is here.

I have a simple $modal popup window in angular using ui-router - when a user clicks on a button and displays info after making an api call. It looks like this.

```
.state('rates.rate.runexperiment', {
    url: "/runexperiment",
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$timeout', 'ExpsService', function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $timeout, ExpsService){
        var modalInst = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "templates/ExpsResults.html",
            windowClass: "full",
            controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$timeout',  function($scope, $state, $timeout) {

                $timeout(function(){
                    $("#modal").resizable();
                },0);


                $scope.expResults = null;

                $scope.getExpResults = function(){
                     ExpsService.getExpResults('1000').then(function(response){
                        $scope.expResults = response;
                    });
                };

                $scope.close = function() {
                    $scope.$close(true);
                    $state.go('rates.rate');
                };

                $scope.getExpResults()
            }]
        });


        modalInst.result.then(function(){

        }, function(){
            $state.go('rates.rate');
        });
    }]
})
```

I have a jquery function in there as you can see. I have all the jquery dependencies for resizable (mouse, widget and core) for this to work.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $("#modal").resizable();
},0);
```

my html template is as follow:

```
<div class="modal-header" id="modal">
    <h3>
        Exp Results 
        <span class="pull-right"> 
            {{expResults.name}}
        </span>
    </h3>
    <ul ng-repeat=data in expResults>
        <li>{{data}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now it gets weird with the $modal because it creates a two div wrappers around your template html: a div with a .modal-content class and the modal-dialog and some fade stuff. I've tried selecting all these with jquery but nothing happens.

I also tried using the resize:both in my css but all the child elements inherit the resize selector and each li element gets a resize along with everything else. Also, resizable when I select the .modal-content class only works when overflow:scroll is set on .modal-content

Could someone shed some light how to just get the $modal dialog box resizable?

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr or jsfiddle please? thx

Comment: Yeah i'll work on it and get back soon

Comment: Are you using the bootstrap modal? If so you can just set the size to 'lg', assuming all you really need is a larger modal window instead of just the ability to resize it.

Comment: Yeah I am, I actually set my own css class to be a certain size. I would still like to be able to resize it though